# Swap capitalization of two strings

Tags: code-golf, string

`your shift key is broken. wheNever you type two lines, the cApitaL`
`LetteRs in them get swappeD. you must write a program to fiX THIS!`

### Description

The input is two strings, `s1` and `s2`, equal in length. They will each contain only printable ASCII and be at least one character in length. You may input these as two strings, an array of two strings, or a single string with `s1` and `s2` separated by either a tab or newline.

The output is the following:

- For each character `c` in `s1`:

  - If the character is not a letter, output it unchanged.
  - Otherwise, if `c` is a letter:

    - Find the matching character (the one at the same index) in `s2`.

      - If it is a capital letter, output `c` capitalized.
      - If it is a lowercase letter, output `c` in lowercase.
      - Otherwise, output `c` unchanged.
- Then do the same thing, except with `s1` and `s2` switched.

Essentially, all letters in `s1` for which the matching character in `s2` is capital should be capitalized, and all letters in `s1` with a lowercase letter at the same index in `s2` should become lowercase (and vice versa).

### Test cases

Input:

```
ABCDEfghijKlMnOpqrstuvwxyz
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa----------
```

Output:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
AAAAAaaaaaAaAaAa----------
```

---

Input:

```
PRogrammiNG puzZLes & CODe golf
SdlkhkfaladlKsdlalksdg7ldklDgsl
```

Output:

```
Programming Puzzles & Code Golf
SDlkhkfalADlksdLAlksdg7LDkldgsl
```

---

Input:

```
AAAbbb111
Cc2Dd3Ee4
```

Output:

```
AaABbb111
CC2dd3Ee4
```

Comment: I cannot for the life of me figure out how this could be caused by a broken shift key, but who am I to argue with the almighty Doorknob? :P

Comment: Does the input have to be on the same line? Or can I use some other character (a tab?) to separate them?

Comment: @Dennis No, the input must be provided as shown in the question.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos You may take either two strings, an array of strings, or two strings separated by either a tab or a newline. I'll edit that into the question.

Comment: is a trailing newline allowed?

Comment: @vihan1086 Yes.

Comment: Is this limited to ANSI chars not Unicode, i.e. there is no concern about Turkish and German for instance?

Comment: @Jodrell "*They will each contain only printable ASCII*"

Comment: so swapping bit 6 would be sufficient?

Comment: @Jodrell Not if the input contains numbers.

Comment: You are not specific on the output format. I am in doubt whether you allow to return a list of items instead of two lines separated by a `\n` character, but I will change my answer from the second to the first, as I've already seen other's answers doing it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
LCmrW&@dG@drG1d2Cb
```

This defines a function **y** that accepts and return a list of strings.

Verify all test cases at once in the [Pyth Compiler/Executor](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=LCmrW%26%40dG%40drG1d2Cb%0A%0Ajb%2BFmydc.z2&input=ABCDEfghijKlMnOpqrstuvwxyz%0Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa----------%0APRogrammiNG+puzZLes+%26+CODe+golf%0ASdlkhkfaladlKsdlalksdg7ldklDgsl%0AAAAbbb111%0ACc2Dd3Ee4&debug=0).

*Thanks to @Jakube for golfing off 1 byte.*

#### How it works

```
                   " (implicit) Initialize G to 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.

L                  " Define y(b):
                Cb "   Zip to turn the two strings into an array of char pairs.
  m                "   Map (implicit variable d):
      @dG          "     Intersect d with G.
         @drG1     "     Intersect d with G.upper().
    W&             "     If both are non-empty:
   r          d2   "       Apply swapcase() to d.
 C                 "   Zip to turn the character pairs back into two strings.
```

Answer (score 12):

## CJam, 25 bytes

```
{z{_el_eu&\__:^32&f^?}%z}
```

This is an anonymous function that pops an array of strings from the stack and leaves one in return.

In supported browsers, you can verify all test cases at once in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F2%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e%23%20Read%20input%20and%20split%20into%20arrays%20of%20two%20strings.%0A%0A%7Bz%7B_el_eu%26%5C__%3A%5E32%26f%5E%3F%7D%25z%7D%0A%0A%25%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e%23%20Map%20the%20block%20over%20all%20string%20arrays.%0A%3A%2BN*%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e%23%20Separate%20the%20strings%20by%20linefeeds.&input=ABCDEfghijKlMnOpqrstuvwxyz%0Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa----------%0APRogrammiNG%20puzZLes%20%26%20CODe%20golf%0ASdlkhkfaladlKsdlalksdg7ldklDgsl%0AAAAbbb111%0ACc2Dd3Ee4).

#### Test cases

**Code**

```
qN/2/                     e# Read input and split into arrays of two strings.

{z{_el_eu&\__:^32&f^?}%z}

%                         e# Map the block over all string arrays.
:+N*                      e# Separate the strings by linefeeds.
```

**Input**

```
ABCDEfghijKlMnOpqrstuvwxyz
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa----------
PRogrammiNG puzZLes & CODe golf
SdlkhkfaladlKsdlalksdg7ldklDgsl
AAAbbb111
Cc2Dd3Ee4
```

**Output**

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
AAAAAaaaaaAaAaAa----------
Programming Puzzles & Code Golf
SDlkhkfalADlksdLAlksdg7LDkldgsl
AaABbb111
CC2dd3Ee4
```

#### How it works

```
z                       e# Zip to transform the array of strings into an array
                        e# of character pairs.
 {                  }%  e# For each character pair:
  _el                   e#   Push a copy and convert to lowercase.
     _eu                e#   Push a copy and convert to uppercase.
        &               e#   Intersect. The result will be an empty string if
                        e#   and only if both characters are letters.
         \              e#   Swap the character pair on top of the stack.
          __            e#   Push two copies.
            :^          e#   XOR both characters.
              32&       e#   Logical AND with 32. This pushes 32 for letters of
                        e#   different cases and 0 for letters of the same case.
                 f^     e#   XOR each character with the result.
                   ?    e#   Select the original copy for non-empty intersection
                        e#   and the modified one otherwise.
                      z e# Zip to turn the characters pairs back into two strings.
```

Answer (score 8):

## C, 126 bytes

This is my first attempt at a code golf, ever. Let me know if I did anything wrong.

I'm using bitwise operations to perform the switching

Golfed:

```c
main(u,a,s,t)char**a,*s,*t;{for(s=a[1],t=a[2];*t;s++,t++)isalpha(*s)*isalpha(*t)?u=(*t^*s)&32,*t^=u,*s^=u:0;*s=10;puts(a[1]);}
```

Ungolfed:

```c
main(u,a,s,t) char**a,*s,*t; {       // K&R style arguments
    for(s=a[1],t=a[2];*t;s++,t++)    // initialize loop.
        isalpha(*s) * isalpha(*t) ? // ensure both characters are letters (if)
            u = (*t^*s) & 0x20,      // check if characters have swapped case
            *t^=u,                   // if so, xor the bit which represents case
            *s^=u                    // for both characters in the string.
        :0;                          // end ternary statement (endif)
    *s=10;                           // replace null terminator in first string 
    puts(a[1]);                      // with newline. This allows both output to 
}                                    // be printed out all at once
```

edit: replaced && with *

Answer (score 6):

## SQL (PostGreSQL), 427 Bytes

Despite it's huge size, this ended up being quite a bit smaller than I expected.  I wasn't quite sure I was going to be able to do it to be honest.  I suspect there is a lot that still can be done:)

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION F(TEXT,TEXT)RETURNS TABLE(S TEXT) AS'SELECT unnest(array[string_agg(CASE WHEN T~''[A-Z]''THEN upper(S)WHEN T~''[a-z]''THEN lower(S)ELSE S END,''''),string_agg(CASE WHEN S~''[A-Z]''THEN upper(T)WHEN S~''[a-z]''THEN lower(T)ELSE T END,'''')])FROM(SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER()N,S FROM regexp_split_to_table($1,'''')X(S))A JOIN(SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER()M,T FROM regexp_split_to_table($2,'''')Y(T))B ON N=M'LANGUAGE SQL
```

Formatted and commented

```sql
-- Declare the function spec
CREATE FUNCTION F(TEXT,TEXT)RETURNS TABLE(S TEXT) AS  
'SELECT unnest(   -- turns array into a table
    array[        -- build array of the column results
    string_agg( -- Aggregate the result into a string
        CASE 
        WHEN T~''[A-Z]''THEN upper(S) -- uppercase it if corresponding char is uppercase
        WHEN T~''[a-z]''THEN lower(S) -- lowercase it if corresponding char is lowercase
        ELSE S END
        ,''''),
    string_agg( -- Same as the previous but swap strings
        CASE 
        WHEN S~''[A-Z]''THEN upper(T)
        WHEN S~''[a-z]''THEN lower(T)
        ELSE T END
        ,'''')
    ])
FROM
    -- split the first string
   (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER()N,S FROM regexp_split_to_table($1,'''')X(S))A
    JOIN
    -- split the second string
   (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER()M,T FROM regexp_split_to_table($2,'''')Y(T))B 
   ON N=M
'
LANGUAGE SQL
```

Test run

```sql
SELECT F(A,B) AS Result
FROM (VALUES 
    ('AAAbbb111', 'Cc2Dd3Ee4'), 
    ('ABCDEfghijKlMnOpqrstuvwxyz', 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa----------'), 
    ('PRogrammiNG puzZLes & CODe golf', 'SdlkhkfaladlKsdlalksdg7ldklDgsl')
    )A(A,B)

Result
-----------------------------
AaABbb111
CC2dd3Ee4
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
AAAAAaaaaaAaAaAa----------
Programming Puzzles & Code Golf
SDlkhkfalADlksdLAlksdg7LDkldgsl
```

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, 140 bytes

```julia
f(s,t)=(C(x,y)=(i=0;z="";for c=x i+=1;z*=string(isalpha(c)?isupper(y[i])?uppercase(c):islower(t[i])?lowercase(c):c:c)end;z);(C(s,t),C(t,s)))
```

This creates a function that accepts two strings and returns a tuple of strings. Nothing particularly clever is going on here; we simply define an inner function that directly implements the algorithm in the spec and call it twice.

Ungolfed:

```julia
function f(s, t)
    C(x, y) = begin
        i = 0
        z = ""
        for c in x
            i += 1
            if isalpha(c)
                if isupper(y[i])
                    z *= string(uppercase(c))
                elseif islower(y[i])
                    z *= string(lowercase(c))
                else
                    z *= string(c)
                end
            else
                z *= string(c)
            end
        end
        return z
    end

    return (C(s, t), C(t, s))
end
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>128</s> 108 bytes

```
s=(a,b,t)=>[...a].map((l,i)=>/[^a-z]/.exec(b[i])?l.toUpperCase():l.toLowerCase()).join``+(t?'':`
`+s(b,a,1))
```

JavaScript's `toUpperCase()` and `toLowerCase()` take up a lot of bytes but `String.fromCharCode()` is even longer

Comment: This doesn't account for the condition where a character in `s2` is not a letter and the corresponding character in `s1` is uppercase. In this case, `c` in `s1` must be returned unchanged.

Comment: @c.P.u1 I've addressed that :)

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, <s>173</s> <s>169</s> 155 bytes

```
f=0>1;t=!f;c=Characters;u=ToUpperCase;StringJoin/@MapThread[#@#2&,{Reverse[{LetterQ@#,#==(u@#)}&/@c@#/.{{f,_}->(#&),{t,t}->u,{t,f}->ToLowerCase}&/@#],c/@#},2]&
```

This is a function taking an array of two strings, e.g. `{"Foo","bAR"}` and outputting an array of two strings.  Un-spatially-compressing it, rewriting the scheme `f@x` as `f[x]` wherever it appears, expanding the notation abbreviations (`f=0>1` a.k.a. `False`,`t=!f` a.k.a. `True`, `c=Characters`, and `u=ToUpperCaseQ`), and un-replacing UpperCaseQ[#] with `#==u@#` (this character equals its uppercased version), it is:

```
StringJoin /@ MapThread[#[#2] &, {
    Reverse[
        { LetterQ[#], UpperCaseQ[#] } & /@ Characters[#] /. 
        { {False, _} -> (# &), {True, True} -> ToUpperCase, 
          {True, False} -> ToLowerCase } & /@ #
    ],
    Characters /@ #
}, 2] &
```

Interfacing:  the trailing `&` makes this a function.  Its argument is inserted as the "#" at both instances of `/@ #`.  For instance `f=0>1; ... & [{"AAAbbb111", "Cc2Dd3Ee4"}]` produces the output `{AaABbb111,CC2dd3Ee4}`.

Processing:  Told in usual outside in order:

- The output of the `MapThread[...]` is a list of two lists of characters.  StringJoin is applied to each of these two lists of characters to produce a list of two strings, the output.
- `MapThread[#[#2]&, ... , 2]` acts on an array of two 2-by-n element lists.  The first list is a 2-by-n array of functions.  The second list is a 2-by-n array of characters, `Characters /@ #`, the lists of characters in the two input strings.  It works at depth 2, i.e., on the functions and individual characters.
- `Reverse[...]` swaps the two sublists of functions so that MapThread will apply the second string's functions to the first string and vice versa.
- `{ ... } &` is an anonymous function that is applied to each of the two input strings.
- `{LetterQ[#], UpperCaseQ[#]} & /@ Characters[#]` splits a string into a list of characters, then replaces each character with two element lists.  In these two element lists, the first element is `True` if the character is a letter and `False` otherwise, similarly, the second element indicates whether the character is upper case.  `UpperCaseQ[]` cannot return true if it does not receive a letter.
- `/. {{False, _} -> (# &), {True, True} -> ToUpperCase, {True, False} -> ToLowerCase}` replaces these two element lists with functions.  (Expansion of the abbreviations `t` and `f` occurs before any matching is attempted.)  If a two element list has `False` as its first element, it is replaced with the function `(# &)`, the identity function.  (The parentheses are necessary, otherwise the arrow binds more tightly than the ampersand.)  Otherwise the two element list starts with `True`, the character was a letter, and we output the functions `ToUpperCase` and `ToLowerCase` corresponding to its case.  (Checking for this last `False` is unnecessary, in fact `{_,_}->ToLowerCase` would work, catching anything that hadn't been replaced yet, but this would be no shorter and more obscure.)

The only challenge was figuring out a succinct way to zip a two dimensional array of functions to an array of arguments.

Edit:  Thanks to @Martin Büttner for catching "helpful" cut/paste linebreak backslashes, the `1>0` and `1<0` abbreviations, and also for the guidance to count length in bytes not characters (whatever those are :-) )

Edit2:  Further thanks to @Martin Büttner for pointing out that polluting the global namespace is acceptable golf, reminding me of one character function application, and suggesting replacing the two uppercase functions with an abbreviation for one and using the one to emulate the other (saving four characters).  (I think he's done this before.  :-)  )

Comment: More golfitude: use `f@g` instead of `f[g]` (throughout your code). I'm also quite sure you don't need a block. Just do `(f=0>1;t=!f;c=Characters;StringJoin/@...)&`. This pollutes the global namespace, but we're totally fine with that when golfing. Also, I haven't counted, but you might be able to save bytes by storing `ToUpperCase` in a variable (`u`, say) and replacing `UpperCaseQ@#` with `#==u@#`.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 131 bytes

```python
def j(s,g):p=lambda s,g:''.join(i.upper()if j.istitle()else i.lower()if j.islower()else i for i,j in zip(s,g));return p(s,g),p(g,s)
```

Function returns strings in a tuple

Comment: @mbomb007 May I ask the point of editing my post? In my opinion strikethroughs are messy, that's why I never use them.

Comment: It's a standard format, and it gives a bit of credit to people that helped you golf it, by showing that this isn't what you originally came up with. Otherwise, in order to see that you changed it significantly at all, they have to view edit history. It's more user-friendly to show the byte-change, but I guess it's up to you whether or not to credit those who helped you.

Comment: See [this meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/860/strike-through-previous-character-counts) for further description of why it's helpful.

Comment: @mbomb007 The accepted answer to the meta post you link says there isn't and doesn't need to be a policy about this, even though it does give reasons one might like to include them, so I think it's up to each poster.

Comment: @xnor Thanks for summarizing what I said above. Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

## Erlang, 157 bytes

```
f(A,B)->S=string,G=fun(A,B)->[if Q>64andalso Q<91->S:to_upper(P);Q>96andalso Q<123->S:to_lower(P);true->P end||{P,Q}<-lists:zip(A,B)]end,G(A,B)++"\n"++G(B,A).
```

Zips the two strings (actually, lists) into a two-character-tuple list and maps each character to the appropriate case using a list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 101 bytes

```py
lambda*I:["".join([a.upper(),a.lower(),a][~-b.isalpha()or"Z"<b]for a,b in zip(*X))for X in I,I[::-1]]
```

An anonymous function which takes two strings and returns the output strings in a list. I've marked this as Python 2 because Python 3 doesn't allow `I,I[::-1]` to sit alone at the end like that.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 126 bytes

```python
t="".join;s="low","upp";y=lambda a,b:eval("a"+".%ser()"%s[b.isupper()]*b.isalpha());f=lambda a,b:(t(map(y,a,b)),t(map(y,b,a)))
```

Function `f` returns strings in a tuple

Comment: That is now fixed, it now works for all the test cases.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 181 bytes

```
char*x,*y;main(int a,char**_){a?x=_[2],y=_[1],main(0,0),putchar(10),x=_[1],y=_[2],main(0,0):(*x?putchar(!isupper(*x)?!islower(*x)?*y:tolower(*y):toupper(*y)),x++,y++,main(0,0):0);}
```

Had trouble shortening standard library names in a worthwhile way, (#define'ing them takes 11 characters of overhead). Uses main recursion and global variables x and y as arguments.

main(<non-zero>,argv) = call main(0,{argv[1],argv[2]}) then print newline then call main(0,{argv[2],argv[1]})

main(0,{x,y}) = if x is end of string return 0, else print correct case of first character of x and call main(0,{x+1,y+1}).

Run with the two strings as arguments.

Comment: Are you stealing my username? ;)

Comment: [147 bytes](https://tio.run/##XUzdCoIwGH0WvZDtc0LpnSLS31VEDxAxxihdmJnT3Pp79bUMvOjAgfPH4UHOuTG8YA0oAjo5M1EhRigeIqDJg2U6Bd@nRKV0N92TYTHB1gIl2mZ110rkunisYlCeN2hH@T7RlnbzPURCdnV9aBAonL2j0AMdg35GITiOkOWl/1UYJy9jzGy@WK6OeSFO63JTbetrI9vu1it9N@wPwYgP "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## C - <s>164</s> 153 Bytes - GCC

```
#define r z[_][w]
main(_,z,w)char**z;{while(--_)for(w=0;r;r+=r<25?97:r<91&&r>64?z[!(_-1)+1][w]-=32,_-1?z[_-1][w]-=97:0,32:0,w++);puts(z[1]),puts(z[2]);}
```

gcc prog.c

./a.out AfdgF a2dfsd

Will update if I can get wc -c down. Works very well actually

Comment: Could you post an ungolfed version? I'm curious how this works, but have a hard time reading through your symbols ;)

Comment: Sure thing. Give me a minute.

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 102

```
$><<gets.chars.zip(gets.chars).map{|i|/[a-z][A-Z]|[A-Z][a-z]/=~i*''?(i.map &:swapcase):i}.transpose*''
```

Takes the original strings, pairs off letters in arrays. If they are either lower/cap or cap/lower, then swapcase on both. Then transpose the arrays back into our ordered array.

This requires a trailing newline in input.

Answer (score 0):

## F#, 211 chars

```
let n x y=List.fold2(fun a i j->a@match j with|c when c>='A'&&c<='Z'->[Char.ToUpper i]|c when c>='a'&&c<='z'->[Char.ToLower i]|_->[i])[](x|>Seq.toList)(y|>Seq.toList)|>String.Concat
let m a b =n a b+"\n"+n b a
```

could be better ...

Answer (score 0):

### Matlab, 140

```
function [s,t]=f(s,t)
c=s>96&s<123;C=s>64&s<91;d=t>96&t<123;D=t>64&t<91;s(c&D)=s(c&D)-32;s(C&d)=s(C&d)+32;t(d&C)=t(d&C)-32;t(D&c)=t(D&c)+32;
```

Ungolfed:

```
function [s,t] = f(s,t)
c = s>96 & s<123;         % letters that are lowercase in 1st string
C = s>64 & s<91;          % letters that are uppercase in 1st string
d = t>96 & t<123;         % letters that are lowercase in 2nd string
D = t>64 & t<91;          % letters that are uppercase in 2nd string
s(c&D) = s(c&D) - 32;     % make uppercase in 1st string
s(C&d) = s(C&d) + 32;     % make lowercase in 1st string
t(d&C) = t(d&C) - 32;     % make uppercase in 2nd string
t(D&c) = t(D&c) + 32;     % make lowercase in 2nd string
```

Example:

```
>> [s,t]=f('PRogrammiNG puzZLes & CODe golf','SdlkhkfaladlKsdlalksdg7ldklDgsl')
s =
Programming Puzzles & Code Golf
t =
SDlkhkfalADlksdLAlksdg7LDkldgsl
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 164 bytes

Pretty much implementing the algorithm as described in the problem. Takes 2 strings as input parameters.

```
char*a,*b;main(c,v)char**v;{for(a=v[1],b=v[2];*a&&*b;++a,++b)isupper(*a)&&islower(*b)?*a+=32,*b-=32:isupper(*b)&&islower(*a)?*b+=32,*a-=32:0;puts(v[1]);puts(v[2]);}
```

Ungolfed:

```
char *a, *b; /* Helpers */

main(c, v)
char **v;
{
    /* While strings not terminated... */
    for (a = v[1], b = v[2]; *a && *b; ++a, ++b)
        isupper(*a) && islower(*b)
            ? *a += 32, *b -= 32 /* Make first string lowercase, second uppercase */
            : isupper(*b) && islower(*a)
                ? *b += 32, *a -= 32; /* Make second string lowercase, first uppercase */

    puts(v[1]); /* print out first string */
    puts(v[2]); /* print out second string */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5.10+, <strike>101</strike> 99 bytes

```
perl -p00e '/\n/;s/([a-z])(?=.{$-[0]}([a-z]))/$x=($1^$2)&" ";$s{$-[2]}=$2^$x;$1^$x/egis;s|.|$s{$-[0]}//$&|eg'
```

96 bytes + 3 bytes for the command line flags `p00`. Takes a single newline-delimited string as input:

```
$ echo -e "AAAbbb111\nCc2Dd3Ee4" | perl -p00e '...'
```

Or you can enter input on STDIN:

```
$ perl -p00e '...'
AAAbbb111 <Enter>
Cc2Dd3Ee4 <Ctrl+D>
```

### Broken down:

```
perl -p00e'  # Slurp everything into $_, print $_ automatically at the end
    /\n/;    # Match first newline, setting $-[0] to length(s1)

    s/
        ([a-z])  # Match a single letter in s1
        (?=
            .{$-[0]}  # Match n chars where n is length(s1) (until corresponding char in s2)
            ([a-z])   # Corresponding letter in s2
        )
    /
        $x=($1^$2)&" ";   # Check whether bit 6 is the same for both chars.
                          # (Only difference between a lowercase and uppercase ASCII letter
                          # is bit 6; ASCII space is 100000 in binary)

        $s{$-[2]}=$2^$x;  # Swap case of corresponding char in s2 and store in %s,
                          # with position as the key

        $1^$x             # Swap case of current char
    /egis;

    s|.|$s{$-[0]}//$&|eg  # Do a second pass through $_. If there's a value stored in %s
                          # corresponding to this position, use it
'
```

Answer (score 0):

## First attempt in scala, 138 chars

```
def f(s:String,t:String)={val g=(a:Char,o:Char)=>if(o.isUpper)a.toUpper else a.toLower;s.zip(t).map(c=>(g.tupled(c),g(c._2, c._1))).unzip}
```

f is a function that take the two input strings and do the job, with a local function, used two times, for changing case of strings.

The same code, with indentation and just a litte more readable names :

```
def f_ungolfed(first : String, second : String) = {
  val aux = (c1: Char, c2: Char) => if (c2.isUpper) c1.toUpper else c1.toLower
    first.zip(second).map(
         c => (aux.tupled(c), aux.tupled(c.swap))
    ).unzip
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
=Œu=/ị"Ɱż"Œs$
```

A monadic Link accepting and returning lists of two "strings" (lists of characters in Jelly).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATUAyv9qZWxsef//PcWSdT0v4buLIuKxrsW8IsWScyT/4bu0w4dZ//9Db2RlR29sZgp4eFBQQ0d4eA)**

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 97 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:''.join([x,chr(ord(x)&95|ord(y)&32)][(x+y).isalpha()]for x,y in zip(a+'\n'+b,b+' '+a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDBT8IwFMbP@lf0RNtskjA0RhIPY1t2QGTBmBiBQ0vXraysswPpFv/3SZ148J2@933v/Q5f1RxyVXodf1x3kuwpI4C4dALhcKdEiVbG3eYaKc2QwYOHuy@rGjwYe3izQsZp8FDURFY5QXjDlQbGbYAoQSsqRBy4LqFDXepAAB2CcWcvznh7sULQnwZhxLNc7GZyXi6qD10fjp8n07TQBZD8m5u/gdgFCCZLlWmy34vnGFTH9v0prcEABIswBZmS3CJemCzyghNJmJzVTBJZ1Cy7l6yQYVbLnuP7PqV0NBrZj2DrhWwcpbd9FiiWxmfYT2ZMkgSxZ0yfSXVKtfVfkyRa9t5cvKWh9fqw59vd/9XTLbNrxOMc4s3k@qrSojwAchH0Ijg694Rd22D3DQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 194 bytes

```
proc C a\ b {proc L x\ y {expr [[set S string] is u $y]?"[$S tou $x]":"[$S is lo $y]"?"[$S tol $x]":"$x"}
lmap x [split $a ""] y [split $b ""] {append s [L $x $y]
append t [L $y $x]}
list $s $t}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBBT4NAEIXv@yteNsSbh6qJiReD0HgoWmNvUg5LFygywMouCm347bjQ1oNz@@blvckbs6NxVE29gwexRYzjDAG6LXock041CEOdGGygTZNXWYRco4XTR488dDYwtYUu4g8zWY3qSeQXlc6q0/GBUSkUOoRaUW7gCHAe2TsXjmc@CqWSSkIjDKx5SmPnlZlX/RRpw3JtPRqOGcY5@FSAuU@ev0yzff65opdqrb4abdrvn64/MPFvrv@GMf72XmeNKMv89RmqPXwEicYVvLWfIKsp5WwjqdgXqSAhaaUlCSq0zO5JFuRnmhhzXTeO48ViwbzdjS9vl8kdG@xLW2O7eFNfJ4621TD@Ag)

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>109</s> 91 bytes

```hs
import Data.Char
(!)=zipWith f
f c|isUpper c=toUpper|isAlpha c=toLower|1<3=id
a#b=[b!a,a!b]
```

Thanks to @Laikoni for 16 bytes!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYxBS8NAEIXv@RWTFKSFKsQKXppDTIqHplYsIrQUmc0m2TWTZN3dWg3973FpwYPvMo9veJ9AUxdEwyAb1WkLKVq8SQRqb@xPol6qN2kFlF4J@UmaV6UKDXlku3NzJCYl8Eyy7uhIOJ9Fkns4YtGO@ThFn@2HBmULETSoVu8wvhx1sBurs3biwQ6C@CFJF2Ul5MeSVu1afWpjD1/H758@GAX4L9d/CTyYQvD80lUam0Y@PTptv80KA1eQrNMCqo5KZ9hwqkVdIiGnpeGEVBte3ROvKa0MXTRxHDPGwjB0gyS/TflsUdy51374BQ)